# Performance of series fans on a heatsink

Tags: fan, heatsink, air-pressure

I have a large heatsink with fans that push air through the heatsink parallel to the fins, very similar to [Fischer Elektronik LA 9 150 230 V](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/heatsinks/6920638/?relevancy-data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searchHistory=%7B%22enabled%22%3Atrue%7D) but not identical. I know that a heatsink increases the static pressure of a fan, reducing total airflow through the heatsink, I also know that having two fans in series increases airflow for a given pressure.

If I was to add another fan to the other side of the heatsink, essentially having two fans "in series", would this increase the cooling capacity of the heatsink?

EDIT: Will performance be increased if the additional fans don't have the same performance characteristics of the first fan? At which point will adding a fan actually reduce the cooling performance of the heatsink?

Comment: How much will the life span of the "hot" fan (the one that's blowing hot air, sourced from the heatsink), be shortened because of this configuration - and is it worth it?

Comment: A really good point to consider actually

Comment: I used a fan on the exhaust port of a circuit and @ChrisKnudsen is right.  That fan gets hot, and when it's hot it may not restart, which then kills the fan permanently.  Also the bearings can fail due to being overheated.